# RAID 10 with external hard drives on linux

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, raid

i recently turned my old laptop (lenovo G550) into a NAS machine running ubuntu server.
since it's a laptop, i can't put more than 1 SATA HDD (or SSD) into it. because of that, i need to use external HDDs.
how would i do a RAID 10 with external HDDs on linux using only the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the answer to RAID10 on Linux is `md`. It is very good software RAID.

However I am not sure that RAID10 is what you want if you need to fall back to USB2 connecter harddrives.

[This](https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-g550-2958-15-6-p-t4200-vista-home-premium-64-bit-4-gb-ram-320-gb-hdd-series/) shows your laptop as having 3 USB 2 ports. That limits a drive to about 30-35MiB/sec. Which means that the disc is likely much faster than the interface. So USB10 (stripe, mirrored) is probably as fast as mirrored.  Which means that RAID1 (mirror) might use have the disc and have near equal performance. <sup>*1</sup>

And depending on the internal layout those 3 USB port might share a combined bandwith, so max speed of 3 external discs might me limited to 35MiB/sec.

that mean that you have a few choices:

1. RAID 10, with all the disc usage of RAID 10 and likely no advantage from half of the discs
2. RAID 1 (mirror)
3. RAID 1E (using 3 or 4 disc in a mirror).
4. Use the ExpressCard/34 interface and add a SATA, SAS or USB3 interface (you will have access to at least one PCI-e lane, so at least 2.5GB/sec which is much faster then USB2)
5. Use portmultiplexing on the internal SATA bus.  Technically SATA will do fine with that, but most laptops do not seem to support it).

Personally I would choose to either:

1. Settle for low cost low USB2 performace. 2 external USB drives, mirrored with mdadm will do just fine
2. Or consider a SATA expresscard/34, wither with 2 ports and 2 drives or with a port multiplexer. The geek in me like the last option but it might not makes the most economical sense.

Last note: Please not that you are limited to 100mbit ethernet. So about 10MB/sec. That means that the network interface might be slower than the disk so that the USB2 RAID mirror makes the most sense.

---

<sup>*1</sup>: unless doing lots of random access.

Comment: tldr for me: "Personally I would choose to either:

    Settle for low cost low USB2 performace. 2 external USB drives, mirrored with mdadm will do just fine"